# Is std::unordered_map thread safe in this case?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, unordered-map

Assume that one thread calls only the following functions continuously. 
here, `insert_data` check whether a key exists in `std::unordered_map`, and if it does not exist, `insert_data` call a function that adds a new key and modifies its values.

```cpp
void insert_data(int key, int value, std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>& my_map)
{
    if (my_map.find(key) == my_map.end())
    {
        my_map[key] = std::vector<int>();
    }

    my_map[key].push_back(value);
}
```

In another thread, it iterate over std::unordered_map over and over again.

```cpp
void iteration(std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>& my_map)
{
    for (auto& [key, value] : my_map)
    {
        std::cout<<"key : "<<key<<" value : "<<value<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is the shared `my_map` thread safe if each of the above functions is executed in only one thread?

Comment: `my_map.find(key) != my_map.end()` means that the key is found. Thus, you reset the vector if it is found meaning the vector is empty in all cases. This does not look what you want based on the description. The `push_back` should certainly be inside the conditional or `==` can be used instead, but `my_map[key] = std::vector<int>()` is useless.

Comment: It is not safe because `insert_data` might add an entry to the map while `iteration` is iterating over it. BTW - `if (my_map.find(key) != my_map.end())` - didn't you mean `==` ?

Comment: `my_map[key]` create the value if it is not already in the map but this cause the map to be possibly resized and buckets to be reallocated (hence not thread safe). If the space is reserved so there is no need to reallocate the buckets, then adding values in the buckets is still not thread safe. Even if it would be, vectors have a similar issue: they are reallocated and not thread safe so you cannot print them while adding item in them. You need a lock or another data structure.

Comment: BTW: If your concern is that the inserter thread is blocked for too long when the second thread loops, I can propose a workaround. But since it's not part of the question, I'll wait until you confirm or deny that

Comment: The rules are very very very very VERY VERY simple. Have two threads accessing the same thing? One modifies it? Not safe.

Comment: @Homer512 What you're saying is exactly what I'm looking for. could you please share it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not safe. Operations that change the size of an STL container are never thread-safe.

Also your insert can be made more efficient:

```cpp
void insert_data(int key, int value,
      std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>& my_map)
{
    my_map[key].push_back(value);
}
```

The `[key]` operator creates the value automatically if it is not present. Even if your code wants to know whether it is a new entry, you can do better like this:

```cpp
void insert_data(int key, int value,
      std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>& my_map)
{
    auto inserted = my_map.emplace(key, std::vector<int>{});
    inserted.first->second.push_back(value);
    bool new_entry = inserted.second;
}
```

This avoids the duplicate lookup. It constructs a temporary vector of zero size but that is cheap.

### Simple fix

The simplest solution is to protect the whole thing with a mutex.

```cpp
class Dict
{
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> map;
public:
    void insert_data(int key, int value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        map[key].push_back(value);
    }
    void iteration()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        for(const auto& key_values: map)
            for(int value: key_values.second)
                std::cout << "key : " << key_values.first
                          << " value : " << value << '\n';
    }
};
```

The main issue is that now the insertion can wait for an extended period until it can progress.

### Buffered fix

To avoid these long latencies, we should decouple the two threads as much as possible. Something like this:

```cpp
class Dict
{
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> map;
    std::mutex deferred_mutex;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> deferred;
public:
    void insert_data(int key, int value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(deferred_mutex);
        deferred[key].push_back(value);
    }
    void iteration()
    {
        std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> new_elements;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> deferred_lock(deferred_mutex);
        deferred.swap(new_elements);
        deferred_lock.unlock();
        for(auto& [key, new_values]: new_elements) {
            std::vector<int>& values = map[key];
            values.insert(values.end(), new_values.begin(),
                          new_values.end());
        }
        for(const auto& key_values: map)
            for(int value: key_values.second)
                std::cout << "key : " << key_values.first
                          << " value : " << value << '\n';
    }
};
```

Basically we keep new elements separately until they can be inserted later. Compared to the cost of doing IO, the extra work for the `iteration()` thread should be negligible.

Instead of having a second `unordered_map`, a `vector<pair<int, int>>` for the key-value pairs would likely be more efficient but that requires benchmarking and knowledge of how often keys are duplicates.